# When I try to upload an image then view it in Codeigniter, I see noimage.jpg instead the uploaded one

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to create a post with an image, but when I try to load it, it only shows the default image (noimage.jpg) instead of the uploaded one.
Here is my controller to create the post

```php
public function create(){
        $data['title'] = 'Crear Entrada';

        $data['categories'] = $this->post_model->get_categories();

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'Body', 'required');

        if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('posts/create', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        } else {
            // Upload Image
            $config['upload_path'] = './assets/images/posts';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '2048';
            $config['max_width'] = '500';
            $config['max_height'] = '500';

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
                $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                $post_image = 'noimage.jpg';
            } else {
                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                $post_image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
            }

            $this->post_model->create_post($post_image);
            redirect('posts');
        }

    }
```

model:

```php
public function create_post($post_image){
        $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'));

        $data = array(
            'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'slug' => $slug,
            'body' => $this->input->post('body'),
            'category_id' => $this->input->post('category_id'),
            'post_image' => $post_image
        );

        return $this->db->insert('posts', $data);
```

And this is the HTML where I try to load the images from

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Cargar Imagen</label>
    <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: provide the name of your file array which is being posted replace the `$this->upload->do_upload()` with `$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')` and print the error by adding `print_r($this->upload->display_errors());` to know the exact error which you are facing while uploading the file.

Step 2: also always use file name which is provided by the `$this->upload->data()`. it will look something like this in your case `$data['upload_data']['file_name']`.